How to check when user comes back to a screen after being navigated to settings, gorouter
context: I am creating a flutter plugin, and i have a button to direct user to settings page
 ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 64),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await _checkAppPlugin.requestLocationPermission();
                  // somehow detect user coming back to this screen and recheck permission
                  //     isPermissionEnabled = await _checkAppPlugin.checkLocationPermission();
                },
                child: const Text('Enable location permission'),
              )

native implementation:
requestLocationPermission(){
    Intent intent = new 
    Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, 
    Uri.parse("package:" + activity.getPackageName()));
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE);
}

i want to detect when user comes back to the screen, so that i can recheck permission.
What i tried: implementing a navigationobserver

final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(  observers: [
    GoRouterObserver(), 
  ],routes:...


class GoRouterObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    print('MyTest didPush: $route');
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    print('MyTest didPop: $route');
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    print('MyTest didRemove: $route');
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic>? newRoute, Route<dynamic>? oldRoute}) {
    print('MyTest didReplace: $newRoute');
  }
}

however, it seems the current page is not removed at all when the user is navigated to the settings page, since didRemove never fire at all

One solution is to check if user is in the current route in the build method in this way:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (ModalRoute.of(context)?.isCurrent ?? false) {
      requestLocationPermission();
    }
    return Scaffolf(...);
  }

